# How can you refer to a generic type as one it inherits from?

Tags: swift, generics

I have a `MutableStorage` protocol which is designed to store the generic `Item` type. I have another protocol `ImmutableStorage` which it inherits from, which is meant to be a read-only version of the `MutableStorage`. This part works fine.

What I would like to do is specify this storage as a generic and have access to *both* the mutable type and immutable types within that class.

For example, this `StorageExample` class takes the `MutableStorage` as a generic which it can use for its mutable property, which is exactly what I want. The problem I run into is in the `colectItems(:)` method where I would prefer to specify the equivalent `ImmutableStorage` type.

Is there a way to do this with the protocols I have defined? Or is the answer that I must not have the protocol inheritance between `MutableStorage`/`ImmutableStorage` and need to have one be an associated type of the other?

```
class StorageExample<S: MutableStorage> {
  private var mutableStorage: S
  init(mutableStorage: S) {
    self.mutableStorage = mutableStorage
  }

  func collectItems(_ collector: (S) -> [S.StorageItem]) {
    let itemUpdates = collector(mutableStorage) // <-- How can I pass an `ImmutableStorage` type
    for item in itemUpdates {
      mutableStorage.contents[item.key] = item
    }
  }
}

/// Read/write storage of the items.
protocol MutableStorage: ImmutableStorage {
  var contents: [StorageItem.Key: StorageItem] { get set }
}

/// Item storage that can be inspected but not changed.
protocol ImmutableStorage {
  associatedtype StorageItem: Item
  var contents: [StorageItem.Key: StorageItem] { get }
}

/// An item that can be stored.
protocol Item {
  associatedtype Key: Hashable
  associatedtype Data
  var key: Key { get }
  var data: Data { get }
}
```

Comment: What would be advantage of doing that, if you could do it? What's the actual goal?

Comment: I agree it does look a bit contrived when simplified down to this example. I have added a comment to your answer below to try and give some more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend for `collector` to accept an ImmutableStorage, you can pass that. I recommend adjusting your ImmutableStorage to a have a primary type:

```
protocol ImmutableStorage<StorageItem> {
    associatedtype StorageItem: Item
    var contents: [StorageItem.Key: StorageItem] { get }
}
```

In which case you can then pass a more appropriate `collector`:

```
func collectItems(_ collector: (any ImmutableStorage<S.StorageItem>) -> [S.StorageItem]) {
```

That said, this would probably be better implemented by passing the contents, which are a value type (and so the mutability doesn't matter):

```
func collectItems(_ collector: ([S.StorageItem.Key: S.StorageItem]) -> [S.StorageItem]) {
    let itemUpdates = collector(mutableStorage.contents)
    ...
```

Comment: I agree with this, but I'd also point out that no undesirable mutation is in fact being performed so it's hard to see what is gained by adding a restriction.

Comment: I suspect the concern is that since `S` is being passed to the collector, if `S` is a reference type then `collector` could mutate it. That said, I agree this design feels overcomplicated, and likely better addressed with value types and fewer protocols/generics. (But maybe there's more to it that isn't obvious here.)

Comment: But surely the real issue here is that protocols don't work the way the OP thinks. It is perfectly legal to conform to ImmutableStorage with a `contents` that is settable.

Comment: I like your suggestion to specify the primary type, I think that solves my issue. re: just passing the contents – That's an interesting idea in general but I have extensions on `ImmutableStorage` that add functionality that I want to be available in the closure, so I think I will pass in the `ImmutableStorage` type rather than have the caller create it in each closure.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this is to just have separate protocols rather than unnecessary inheritance. This lets you refer to the immutable type directly via the associated type.

```
/// Item storage that can be inspected but not changed.
protocol ImmutableStorage {
  associatedtype StorageItem: Item
  var contents: [StorageItem.Key: StorageItem] { get }
}

protocol MutableStorage {
  associatedtype Immutable: ImmutableStorage  // <-- Can refer to the Immutable storage type
  var contents: [Immutable.StorageItem.Key: Immutable.StorageItem] { get set }
  var readOnly: Immutable { get }
}

class StorageExample<S: MutableStorage> {

  func collectItems(_ collector: (S.Immutable) -> [S.Immutable.StorageItem]) { 
    (...)
  }
}
```